Difference between vsnprintf on Linux vs Windows
I came across a formatting problem in my code. Here is the issue:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>

void PP_p_VSPF_vsprintf(char *buf, size_t max_size, const char *fmt, va_list args )
{
  const int stat = vsnprintf(buf, max_size, fmt, args);

  if(stat >= static_cast<int>(max_size)) // not enough room in buffer
  {
    buf[max_size - 1] = '\0';
  }
  else if (stat < 0)
  {
    buf[max_size - 1] = '\0';
  }
}


void PP_p_SPF_sprintf(char *buf, size_t max_size, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr, fmt);
  PP_p_VSPF_vsprintf( buf, max_size, fmt, argptr );
  va_end( argptr );
}

int main() {
 char ExpCrcData[100] = "";

 unsigned int crc32Values[] = {0xe870cde0u, 0x1ec5adaeu, 0xcb43101bu};

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

    PP_p_SPF_sprintf(ExpCrcData, 100, "%s0x%08x ", ExpCrcData, crc32Values[i]);

    std::cout << "Download admin string is now: " << ExpCrcData << std::endl;
 }

return 0;
}

Using GNU compiler,
In Windows, I get the output:
Download admin string is now: 0xe870cde0
Download admin string is now: 0xe870cde0 0x1ec5adae
Download admin string is now: 0xe870cde0 0x1ec5adae 0xcb43101b
In Linux, I get the output:
Download admin string is now: 0xe870cde0
Download admin string is now: 0x1ec5adae
Download admin string is now: 0xcb43101b
Can someone explain the reason behind this difference?

Hi!  Please don't tag [c] for [c++] code

Aside: else if (stat < 0) { buf[max_size - 1] = '\0'; makes more sense as else if (stat < 0) {    buf[0] = '\0';.  If code gets an encoding error, best to return "".

https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf says:

C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call
to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause
copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the
target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to
the same buffer).

Because the question is tagged C and C++, here the C++ quote:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf says:

If a call to sprintf or snprintf causes copying to take place between
objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined (e.g. sprintf(buf, "%s text", buf);).

buf and the buffer pointed to by the variable argument corresponding to the %s specifier are overlapping, which is undefined behavior.
Therefore
PP_p_SPF_sprintf(ExpCrcData, 100, "%s0x%08x ", ExpCrcData, crc32Values[i]);

should be
PP_p_SPF_sprintf(ExpCrcData+strlen(ExpCrcData), 100-strlen(ExpCrcData), "0x%08x ",  crc32Values[i]);

Another possibility is to keep track of where you are in the buffer and what's left.

buf and format are not overlapping. buf and the buffer pointed to by the variable argument corresponding to the %s specifier are overlapping.

@IanAbbott yes, sure. I changed the text. Thanks.

@mch Is it possible to have some change in  PP_p_VSPF_vsprintf function itself, as that would solve problems for all appearances of PP_p_SPF_sprintf in my code. Due to some restrictions, changing at high level is not possible (more than 500 occurrences present!!).

@PiyushKumarGupta Just for this case that buf and the first variable argument are equal? Check that the format string starts with %s, get the first variable argument, compare to buf. If yes, do buf +=strlen(buf); fmt +=2; and use argptr, where you already extracted the first element.

@mch I just wished for a general solution to this problem. Many modules of the code use this function in different aspects. It is difficult to analyze them, hence if you suggest an alternate function for vsnprintf in Linux, that is also fine or some tweaks in PP_p_VSPF_vsprintf or PP_p_SPF_sprintf is also highly appreciated
